# A little confused on this recursion example

Tags: c++, recursion

```
int gcd (int a, int b)
{
   if (b == 0)
      return a;
   if (a == 0)
      return b;
   return gcd (b, a % b);
}
```

What is the result of gcd (5, 15)?

I ended up getting 15 but I'm not sure if it's correct, all the loops are confusing me.

Comment: gcd(5, 15) = 5. An example of an algorithm for gcd is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm.

Comment: Step through the algorithm. Show us why you think it's 15. Note that although the arguments are passed in as `(a, b)`, the order changes to `(b, a % b)`.

Comment: @aryamccarthy made a dumb mistake of skipping a recursive call

Comment: If `gcd` is supposed to stand for Greatest Common Denominator, then `gcd(5, 15)` should be 5, not 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the recursive calls that are made in order

```
gcd(5, 15)
gcd(5, 5) # Because 5 % 15 = 5
gcd(5, 0)
```

So the return value of gcd(5, 15) is 5

Answer (score 0):

Let a = 5 and b = 15;

In the first loop we check if either of a and b are 0 , they are not so we call

gcd(15,0); because 5%15 = 5.

So a = 15 , b = 5.

we call gcd(5,15%5) i.e gcd(5,0).

The answer is 5;

Answer (score 0):

See the recursive calls in this way:

```
gcd(5, 15)
        |
    gcd(15,  5 (as 5 % 15)  )   // 'b' simply takes position of 'a'
               | 
           gcd(5,  0 (as 15 % 5) )
                     |
                if (b == 0) return a; // a is 5, so returned value is 5.

           return 5;

    return 5; 

return 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

`gcd (5, 15)` returns `gcd (15, 5 % 15) == gcd (15, 5)`, which in turn returns `gcd (5, 5 % 15) == gcd (5, 5)`, which returns `gcd (5, 5 % 5) == gcd (5, 0) == 5`. So you should be returning 5.

A good way to see what's happening is to insert `printf` statements at the beginning of the function  and at the two final return points showing what happens:

```
gcd(5,15)
gcd(15,5)
gcd(5,0)
5
```

An example Python implementation:

```
def gcd (a, b):
    print("gcd({0},{1})".format(a, b))
    if b == 0:
        print(a)
        return a
    if a == 0:
        print(b)
        return b
    return gcd (b, a % b)

gcd(5,15)
```